# Photoshop Script - create new fill layer behind image

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

I'm currently having an issue whereby I am creating some images and need to create a fill layer behind the current one. Currently the new layer sits on top of the image which gives me a white file. This new white layer needs to be the last layer so the image file can sit above the fill layer.

Code is below

```
var NoImages = File.openDialog("Select your logo file", false);

if (NoImages !== null) { 
    var doc = open(NoImages, OpenDocumentType.PNG.JPEG); // Open PNG file

    if (doc == null) {
      throw "Something is wrong with the file.";
    }

    var startState = doc.activeHistoryState;       // save for undo
    var initialPrefs = app.preferences.rulerUnits; // will restore at end
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;     // use pixels

    // Folder selection dialog
    var destFolder = Folder.selectDialog( "Choose an output folder");

    if (destFolder == null) {
      // User canceled, just exit
      throw "";
    }

    // Save icons in PNG using Save for Web.
    var sfw = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    sfw.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    sfw.PNG8 = false; // use PNG-24
    sfw.transparency = true;
    doc.info = null;  // delete metadata

   var no_images = [
      {"name": "no-image-1-1", "width":1170, "height":1170},
      {"name": "no-image-2-3", "width":779, "height":1170},
      {"name": "no-image-3-2", "width":1170, "height":779},
      {"name": "no-image-3-4", "width":879, "height":1170},
      {"name": "no-image-4-3", "width":1170, "height":879},
      {"name": "no-image-7-2", "width":1170, "height":334},
      {"name": "no-image-9-3", "width":1170, "height":391},
      {"name": "no-image-11-5", "width":1170, "height":532},
      {"name": "no-image-16-9", "width":1170, "height":658}
    ];

    var no_image;
    for (i = 0; i < no_images.length; i++)  {
        no_image = no_images[i];
        doc.resizeCanvas(no_image.width, no_image.height, // width, height
        null, ResampleMethod.BICUBICSHARPER);

        var layerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add();
        layerRef.name = "fill";  
        var myColor = new SolidColor();  
        myColor.rgb.red = 255;  
        myColor.rgb.green = 255;  
        myColor.rgb.blue = 255;  
        activeDocument.selection.fill( myColor); 

        var destFileName = no_image.name + ".png";
        doc.exportDocument(new File(destFolder + "/" + destFileName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, sfw);
        doc.activeHistoryState = startState; // undo resize
    }

alert("No Images created!");

}
```

Comment: Can you not just swap the current active layer with the fill layer?

Answer (score 1):

Would this what you're looking to do? Duplicate the background layer and then target the Background with the fill color?

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;

var layerRef = docRef.layers.getByName ("Background").duplicate(); //duplicates the background layer
layerRef.name = "logo"; //renames the duplicated layer.

docRef.activeLayer = docRef.layers.getByName ("Background");//selects the Background layer

var myColor = new SolidColor();  
myColor.rgb.red = 255;  
myColor.rgb.green = 255;  
myColor.rgb.blue = 255;  

activeDocument.selection.fill( myColor); //fills background layer with white.
```